# How do I switch to using Core Data for a simple UITableView instead of an NSArray?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have an application that uses a `UITableView` to present data that I have stored in an `NSArray`.

I would like to switch over to using Core Data to host this information to be presented to the table view, but I'm not that familiar with Core Data.

I've created a new Core Data database within my project, but I'm lost as to how to proceed pst this point.  What are the steps required to have my `UITableView` pull its information from the Core Data database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, it would take a while to walk you through each step required to do this, so I recommend consulting the many good resources out there before starting to implement Core Data in your application.

There are several questions here that provide a long list of highly recommended resources for getting started with Core Data:

- [Starting point in learning Core Data on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164300/starting-point-in-learning-core-data-on-iphone)
- [New to Core Data for iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656476/new-to-core-data-for-iphone)
- [Cocoa Core Data newbie how-tos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714054/cocoa-core-data-newbie-how-tos)
- [Best ressources for learning Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956841/best-ressources-for-learning-core-data)
- [Adding Core Data to an existing iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026000/adding-core-data-to-an-existing-iphone-app)

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a lot here :) There are plenty of good tutorials in the wild web that you can read. Here is [one](http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-core-data-uitableview-drill-down/) :)

Also look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864218/ios-objc-storing-user-input-and-retrieving-it/3864397#3864397) to this question for your alternatives to Core Data

> Property Lists is the easiest and most
>   basic one in terms of functionality.
>   It just lets you store primitives, but
>   is good if your TODO list is just a
>   collection of Strings.
>
> Serilization using NSCoding is more
>   powerful, but requires more work from
>   the developer. With NSCoding you can
>   create your own coders/decoders for
>   your business objects that lets you
>   persist the entire state. This would
>   be good if you have your own Todo with
>   a lot of properties, like title,
>   priority, complete-by-date etc.

Comment: Hi, In many tutorials, they create a new Project as a Navigation Based Application. But i dont need that type of applications. I want to use core data for my ordinary UITableView's data. It is possible?

Comment: Yes, just create whatever application type you need :)

Comment: Core Data is kind of complex. You can't just save an array. There are many things you need to do. I would just go through a tutorial until you see what code needs to be added to your project then just add the code once you understand it.

Comment: @Velmurugan: To give you some idea how complex it is, asking "how do I use core data?" is almost like asking "how do I write my application?"

Comment: @Nimrod: I have no idea about Coredata. I am fresher in IPhone application development field. i go through a tutorial. but i cant able to understand how to implement it. i dont know how to give connection, like this. Now i created just an application using NSArray. Now i need to store that NSArray into Coredata